# Search box to advanced URL

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a search engine on my site and the URL for the SERPs are `search/QUERY/1/`.

How can I make an HTML search box to fill in the `QUERY` section of my URL?

It can't really use PHP but it could use javascript if it has to.

Comment: You would have to use Javascript, which is why it's not really an encourage-worthy practice IMO.

Comment: Here's a good duplicate: [Nice search URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890272/nice-search-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="word" />
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

index.php :

```
<?PHP
if( isset( $_POST['word'] ) )
{
    header( 'location: /search/' . $_POST['word'] . '/' );
    exit();
}
//Other index.php codes
?>
```

Comment: yes, you could, but you must put it in top of index.php and for better optimize, put : exit(); affter header line.

Answer (score 5):

using jQuery:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yDbAu/1/)**

```
$('#search_button').click(function() {
    var query = encodeURIComponent($('#search_query').val());
    var searchurl = 'http://www.mysite.com/search/{query}/1/';
    var newurl = searchurl.replace('{query}',query);
    alert(newurl);
    // $(location).attr('href',newurl);
});

<input type="text" id="search_query">
<input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search">
```

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks. I assumed the browser would handle that functionality. :)

Comment: you should probably have a replace of ' ' with '+' so you don't have horrible '%20's.